# Multiple views in project

Tags: .net, mvvm-light

I want to create a project that contains 2 views and 2 viewmodels.
One of the views will display persons that i get from a feed and the other will display the weather which I also receive from a feed.

Now in my viewmodellocator constructor I have 
 static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            Container = new UnityContainer();

```
        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            Container.RegisterType<IPersonService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            Container.RegisterType<IPersonService, PersonService>();
        }

        Container.RegisterType<MainViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }

    // Access

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

then I set to use it in the view

But how can I add my weather view? In main my constructor looks like this
public MainViewModel(ICommentService commentsService)

do I need an additional parameter in the constructor?

would appreciate if anyone could help

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't register my Views with my container - only my ViewModels. I typically only have a single instance of any view, so I just create a new instance inside of it's parent ViewModel.

Comment: Yes but I have many instances of the same view (only with different url)

Comment: So you can send a notificationMessage with the url if needed.